# Sending arguments from Batch file to Python script

Tags: python, batch-file, windows-xp

I'm running Python 3.2 on Win XP. I run a python script thru a batch file via this:

`C:\Python32\python.exe test.py %1`

`%1` is an argument that i pass to do some processing in the python script.

I have 2 variables in the batch file that I also want to send as arguments to the python script.

`set $1=hey_hi_hello`

`set $2=hey_hi`

I want to be able to do something like this if possible:

`C:\Python32\python.exe test.py %1 $1 $2`

And then retrieve these argiments in the python script via `sys.argv[2]` and `sys.argv[3]`

Would appreciate any help with this. Thank you.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

your_script.bat:

```
set VAR_1=this
set VAR_2=that

python your_script.py %1 %VAR_1% %VAR_2%
```

Comment: @Tim Henigan: I think you meant `python test.py %1 %VAR_1% %VAR_2%`

Comment: Note that this applies to any sort of environment variable, local or global. So you could do something like `python %USERPROFILE%\scripts\test.py %1 %VAR_1% %VAR_2%`.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to write arguments right after the python script, following the example:

`python your_script.py this that`

If you are using Linux `.sh` file, remember to run `dos2unix XXX.sh` before you run:
`bash XXX.sh`.

The reason, in a simple version, is that dos and unix use different newline breakers.