# Calling my own python script via a batch file

Tags: python, batch-file

I wrote a script in Python and then found another one on github that is very useful.  I would like to automate a larger task containing both of these scripts.  I have a batch file as follows:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:." %%x in ('chcp') do set cp=%%x
chcp 1252>nul
cd C:\python_projects\json_to_csv
gen_outline.py --collection objects F:\electoral_map\%1\candidates\candidates_Bloc_Québécois.json
json2csv.py F:\electoral_map\%1\candidates\candidates_Bloc_Québécois.json F:\electoral_map\%1\candidates\candidates_Bloc_Québécois.outline.json
gen_outline.py --collection objects F:\electoral_map\%1\candidates\candidates_Christian_Heritage.json
json2csv.py F:\electoral_map\%1\candidates\candidates_Christian_Heritage.json F:\electoral_map\%1\candidates\candidates_Christian_Heritage.outline.json
gen_outline.py --collection objects F:\electoral_map\%1\candidates\candidates_Conservative.json
json2csv.py F:\electoral_map\%1\candidates\candidates_Conservative.json F:\electoral_map\%1\candidates\candidates_Conservative.outline.json
gen_outline.py --collection objects F:\electoral_map\%1\candidates\candidates_Forces_et_Démocratie.json
json2csv.py F:\electoral_map\%1\candidates\candidates_Forces_et_Démocratie.json F:\electoral_map\%1\candidates\candidates_Forces_et_Démocratie.outline.json
gen_outline.py --collection objects F:\electoral_map\%1\candidates\candidates_Green_Party.json
json2csv.py F:\electoral_map\%1\candidates\candidates_Green_Party.json F:\electoral_map\%1\candidates\candidates_Green_Party.outline.json
gen_outline.py --collection objects F:\electoral_map\%1\candidates\candidates_Liberal.json
json2csv.py F:\electoral_map\%1\candidates\candidates_Liberal.json F:\electoral_map\%1\candidates\candidates_Liberal.outline.json
gen_outline.py --collection objects F:\electoral_map\%1\candidates\candidates_Libertarian.json
json2csv.py F:\electoral_map\%1\candidates\candidates_Libertarian.json F:\electoral_map\%1\candidates\candidates_Libertarian.outline.json
gen_outline.py --collection objects F:\electoral_map\%1\candidates\candidates_NDP.json
json2csv.py F:\electoral_map\%1\candidates\candidates_NDP.json F:\electoral_map\%1\candidates\candidates_NDP.outline.json
replace_first_line.py F:\electoral_map\%1\candidates\candidates_Conservative.csv F:\electoral_map\%1\candidates\candidates_Conservative_namefixed.csv
chcp %cp%>nul
pause
```

I wrote "replace_first_line.py" and the other two scripts ("gen_outline.py" and "json2csv.py") were taken from github.

This is replace_first_line.py:

```
from sys import argv

def replace_first_line(fin_path, fout_path):

    with open(fin_path) as fin:
        lines = fin.readlines()
        lines[0] = lines[0].replace('district_name,elected_office,election_name,email,extra_facebook,extra_instagram,extra_linkedin,extra_twitter,extra_youtube,first_name,gender,incumbent,last_name,name,offices_0_tel,offices_0_type,party_name,personal_url,photo_url,related_boundary_url,related_election_url,source_url,url',
                                    'district_name,elected_office,election_name,email,extra_facebook,extra_instagram,extra_linkedin,extra_twitter,extra_youtube,first_name,gender,incumbent,last_name,name_,offices_0_tel,offices_0_type,party_name,personal_url,photo_url,related_boundary_url,related_election_url,source_url,url')

    with open(fout_path, 'w') as fout:
        for line in lines:
            fout.write(line)

replace_first_line(argv[1], argv[2])
```

The "replace_first_line.py" works fine when I run it in my IDE, replacing "argv[1]" for the same parameter that I would pass into the batch file.  When I call the batch file with that parameter, it does not work (I changed it back to "argv[1]" first)

The rest of the scripts work, so what gives? Admittedly, my script was written in a Python 3 environment, but I don't think that there is anything in there that isn't also in Python 2.

Comment: In your batch file you're passing in F:\electoral_map\%1\candidates\candidates_Conservative.csv F:\electoral_map\%1\candidates\candidates_Conservative_namefixed.csv; in your function, you're sticking that into {0} ... that's going to result in replace_first_line getting passed F:\electoral_map\F:\electoral_map\{WHATEVER %1 gets set to}\candidates\candidates_Conservative.csv\candidates\candidates_Conservative.csv ... I don't think that's what you want... is that a typo in your question or your problem?

Comment: It's not a mistake, what actually gets passed as %1 is 20150915 (representing a date in format YYYYMMDD, this date is the name of the folder that I am working in that day).  So what I actually call is my_bat_file.bat 20150915 and it should do the rest on its own

Comment: To clarify, I _think_ you're confusing what argv is going to be... there's the argument you pass to the batch file (%1)... but sys.argv[] inside your python program is the first argument passed to it (which is going to be F:\electoral_map\%1\candidates\candidates_Conservative.csv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bottom line: you're inserting the filename into the filename.
In your python file, you want to do

```
replace_first_line(argv[1],argv[1].replace(".csv","namefixed.csv")
```

As otherwise, what gets ultimately passed to replace_first_line if you pass in 20150915 to your batch file is `F:\electoral_map\F:\electoral_map\20150915\candidates\candidates_Conservative.csv\candidates\candidates_Conservative.csv`
(note the two f:\ etc.)

Comment: I see what you mean and I changed the python script and batch file in the original post, but it still doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: I'm getting so frustrated with this, when I copy+paste the exact arguments out of the batch file and drop them into the python script (surrrounding it with r"" and chaning %1 to 20150915), it works fine.  But when I call the batch file, it doesn't work.

LOL NEVERMIND IM A MORON! I was actually editing a different version of the script that I had erroneously saved in a different folder.  Boy is my face red.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

[Sending arguments from Batch file to Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10823033/sending-arguments-from-batch-file-to-python-script)

check this out, it may help. batch files and python scripts use arguments differently and so it may have something to do with how you are passing the argument.