# Sending AND RETURNING arguments from Batch file to Python script

Tags: batch-file

There is already a thread open on [Sending arguments from Batch file to Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10823033/sending-arguments-from-batch-file-to-python-script). And this is working fine.

However, there seems to be an issue with returning an argument value back from that Python script.

I am calling my Python script with two parameters. The first is a string and the second is an environment variable `%project_name%` that has been initialized with string `hello`.

The Python script processes the input string `sys.argv[1]` and extracts the substring from beyond the final `\` in the string. This substring is then copied into `sys.argv[2]` and then should be the new value of variable `%project_name%`.

However, when I run this first from Windows command line, everything works okay except that the updated `sys.argv[2]` is not passed back to `%project_name%`.

See the commands below executed in a command prompt window:

```
set project_name=hello

echo "%project_name%"
"hello"

"C:\python27\python" GetProject.py "#p=/Product Delivery/Product Delivery.pj#s=Team Projects/Team Projects.pj#s=Platform Pack/Platform Pack.pj#s=GERAN SAT(A)/project.pj" %project_name%
Extracting project
project.pj
Returning project
project.pj

echo "%project_name%"
"hello"
```

My Python script is:

```
import os, sys
stext = sys.argv[1]
startpos = stext.rindex("/") # get the final "/" character in the input    string
rtext = stext[startpos+1:]  # extracty the substring after this delimiter 
print "Extracting project "
print rtext
sys.argv[2] = rtext  # return this to the calling program
print "Returning project "
print sys.argv[2]
```

What I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use a Python script for getting from a string the substring between last `/` and end of string or between last `/` and last period. This can be done using for example command **FOR**.

Example to demonstrate this feature of command processor:

The batch file is:

```
@echo off
if "%~1" == "" goto :EOF
for %%I in ("%~1") do set "project_name=%%~nI"
echo Project name is: %project_name%
```

The batch file above is called with parameter:

```
"#p=/Product Delivery/Product Delivery.pj#s=Team Projects/Team Projects.p j#s=Platform Pack/Platform Pack.pj#s=GERAN SAT(A)/My Project.pj"
```

The output is:

```
Project name is: My Project
```

Using `%%~nxI` instead of `%%~nI` in batch file results in output:

```
Project name is: My Project.pj
```

This works as command processor interprets `/` like `\` in a file/folder string for compatibility with Unix paths.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?`
- `for /?`

On help output for those two commands the special codes `%~1`, `%%~nxI` and `%%~nI` are explained which are designed for file and folder names. But `%%~nxI` and `%%~nI` work also for any other string if the command processor does not need to find out where the file/folder with the given string is stored because there is at least one backslash or forward slash and one period after last `/` or `\` in string.

Well, the batch file could be also:

```
@echo off
if "%~1" == "" goto :EOF
set "project_name=%~n1"
echo Project name is: %project_name%
```

---

But I want to answer also your question and explain why your approach can't work at all.

Command processor `cmd.exe` expands `%project_name%` to its value `hello` before running Python. The Python script gets passed from command processor the string `hello` and not the name of the environment variable.

The string `hello` is stored in a memory block allocated by Windows from entire RAM for the called Python interpreter. Also allocated in this memory block is an array of 3 pointers pointing to the 3 argument strings in memory.

I'm not a Python expert, but the line `sys.argv[2] = rtext` most likely results in deallocating the memory used for string `hello` and assigning address of string variable `rtext` to third pointer in pointer array `sys.argv`.

This string memory and pointer management has of course no effect on environment table of the command processor hold in RAM on a completely different address.

Working would be to print the determined string to device **stdout** which is redirected by command processor and the string written to the device **stdout** is assigned to the environment variable `project_name`.

Python script `GetProject.py` is:

```
import os, sys
stext = sys.argv[1]
startpos = stext.rindex("/") # get the final "/" character in the input string
rtext = stext[startpos+1:]   # extract the substring after this delimiter 
print rtext                  # output string to device stdout
```

And this Python script is called from batch file with:

```
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('C:\python27\python.exe GetProject.py "#p=/Product Delivery/Product Delivery.pj#s=Team Projects/Team Projects.p j#s=Platform Pack/Platform Pack.pj#s=GERAN SAT(A)/project.pj"') do set "project_name=%%I"
```

But using a Python script for getting name of project file with or without file extension is definitely not necessary.

Comment: Hi, MofiMany thanks - this works perfectly. I had tried looking up on Google how to handle substrings in DOS, but obviously did not look in the right place. THis

Comment: Sorry finger trouble - sent my reply prematurely. i meant to also state that this help has been very useful as we use a lot of DOS batch files in our build process. Once again many thanks