# How to catch the string, int argument and print variables passed from batch file to python script?

Tags: python-2.7, batch-file

Now I am able to pass the whole list from batch file to python but I want to pass the each element in each looping. How can I achieve this?

**sub.py**

```
import subprocess
import random

item = subprocess.Popen(["test.bat", str(random.randrange(0,20))] , 
                         shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in item.stdout:
    print line
```

**test.bat**

```
set list=hai hello trial 
(for %%a in (%list%) do ( 
   echo %%a 
))
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10823033/sending-arguments-from-batch-file-to-python-script)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending arguments from Batch file to Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10823033/sending-arguments-from-batch-file-to-python-script)