# variable from batch file to python

Tags: python, batch-file

**Updated because of comments

I am trying to pass a variable from a batch file to my python files. I am getting a n unexpected result; my code:

In my batch file:

```
SET variablename = 'name'
python 01_preparing.py %variablename%
```

In my python file

```
import sys

print('Argument:', sys.argv[1])
```

Result is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "01_preparing.py", line 5, in <module>
print('Argument:', sys.argv[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Started out with this example: [Sending arguments from Batch file to Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10823033/sending-arguments-from-batch-file-to-python-script)

Comment: you want another `%` sign, i.e. `python 01_preparing.py %variablename%` might work.  (I'm typing this from a linux box and my memory is ~10 years old)

Comment: 1) you use a variable with `%variablename%`. 2) remove any spaces around `=`  - they become part of the variable name / it's value.

Comment: it doesnt seem to work; I am probably implementing it wrong, ill update the question

Comment: ok. So I should use os in stead of sys

Comment: Both are possible. But in this case `os.environ` should work fine, since the python process can access environment variables from the parent process. (`SET` creates an environment variable)

Comment: Ok so my mistake was that it should be: SET variablename= 'name'. Without a space between variablename and =. It somehow took a space with it in the background. Works now :) thanks!

Comment: @Zuenie, that is what Stephan was pointing out with his 2nd bullet point.  But if you would open up a command prompt and type: `set /?`, you could read the help file, which shows the correct syntax. `SET [variable=[string]]`.  No spaces in that syntax.